# Flutter Console Log can't stop running

Tags: flutter

I am learning flutter recently for my project, and during my experiments I was trying to use other's code from github (link: [click here](https://github.com/MDSADABWASIM/Toughest)) as my reference. And actually, when I was trying to run the code I downloaded, I didn't know what I encountered, but now when I run another (unconnected, different project) code, even the flutter starting code which has absolutely no error, the program can't stop running once I run the program, and it always gives unending console logs like this:

> Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
> E/flutter ( 7946): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart': Failed assertion: line 179 pos 7: 'positions.isNotEmpty': PageController.page cannot be accessed before a PageView is built with it.
> E/flutter ( 7946): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:42:39)
> E/flutter ( 7946): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:38:5)
> E/flutter ( 7946): #2      PageController.page (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:179:7)
>
> ...
>
> E/flutter ( 7946): 
> E/flutter ( 7946): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart': Failed assertion: line 179 pos 7: 'positions.isNotEmpty': PageController.page cannot be accessed before a PageView is built with it.
> E/flutter ( 7946): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:42:39)
> E/flutter ( 7946): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:38:5)
> E/flutter ( 7946): #2      PageController.page (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:179:7)
> E/flutter ( 7946): #3      CarouselState.initState. (package:carousel_pro/src/carousel_pro.dart:110:24)
> E/flutter ( 7946): #4      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
> E/flutter ( 7946): #5      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
> E/flutter ( 7946): #6      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
> E/flutter ( 7946): #7      _CustomZone.bindUnaryCallbackGuarded. (dart:async/zone.dart:970:26)
> E/flutter ( 7946): #8      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1138:13)
> E/flutter ( 7946): #9      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
>
>
> ...

instead of just indicating hot restart, and I don't think the logs are important enough. Can I ask for explanation and how to stop this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Please help to share the code

Comment: @Ashok Sorry, here is the link to the code before I encountered the issue: https://github.com/MDSADABWASIM/Toughest . But the code I ran when I got those issues is just the starting code in main.dart of the flutter when we first create a new project, with the white background and increment counter UI.